# Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name) equivalent in starbasic

Tags: excel, libreoffice, openoffice-calc, vba

What is the equivalent of

```
 Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name)
```

In libre office macro (StarBasic)

I would like to use  Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name) like

below

```
 With Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name)

While (.Worksheets(ConstData.Detail).Range(ConstData.detailDtId + CStr(count)).Value <> 0)

//Some Code

Wend


End With
```

How to do this in Libre Office Calc Macro

Comment: You can try `Dim document as Object` and then `document = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Frame`

Answer (score 2):

An example from the Open Office BASIC Guide:

```
Dim Doc As Object
Dim Sheet As Object
Dim CellRange As Object

Doc = ThisComponent
Sheet = Doc.Sheets.getByName("Sheet 1")
CellRange = Sheet.getCellRangeByName("A1:C15")

MsgBox CellRange.computeFunction(com.sun.star.sheet.GeneralFunction.AVERAGE)
```

http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/BASIC_Guide/Structure_of_Spreadsheets
http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/BASIC_Guide/Editing_Spreadsheet_Documents

Comment: Actually I am getting a problem in the while loop while executing. The error is as follows "BASIC runtime error.
'1'

Type: com.sun.star.container.NoSuchElementException
Message: "

Comment: It may be best to post that code and see if anyone can run / debug it.